# Getting an object of array when fetching value of dijit checkbox instead of a single variable

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am fetching data from a form that contain `dijit/form/CheckBox` and `dijit/form/NumberTextBox` using the code

```
var registry = require("dijit/registry");
var data = registry.byId(formid).get('value');
```

The console output of the above code is

`Object{ COUNTY_TAX_AMT:12,COUNTY_TAX_USE_TYPE:Array[1] }`

The `COUNTY_TAX_USE_TYPE` is the checkbox value

the value of checkbox is getting as an object with an array but the numbertextbox value is getting as a single number variable as expected
How to get the value of `dijit.form.CheckBox` also as single variable instead of getting as an array within js object.

Comment: Is there any way to do it

Comment: What is the output of the array in `COUNTY_TAX_USE_TYPE`?